# Spring MVC with Hibernate and Hibernate Search

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, hibernate-search

I am new to Spring MVC and am building a website using Spring MVC with Hibernate and Hibernate Search and need some help.

I am running this on Java 7 (jdk1.7.0_21), JBoss Wildfly (wildfly-8.2.0.Final) and MySQL 5

I am have the following version in my pom:
Spring 4.2.0.RELEASE
Hibernate 4.2.0.Final
Hibernate Search 4.2.0.Final

root-context.xml:

```
...
<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
<property name="packagesToScan" value="uk.co.fmdj.entity" />
<property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
<bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
<property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
</bean>
</property>
<property name="jpaPropertyMap" ref="jpaPropertyMap" />
</bean>

<util:map id="jpaPropertyMap">
<entry key="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup" />
<entry key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false" />
<entry key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="false" />
<entry key="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.lucene_version" value="LUCENE_35" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/opt/resources/lucene/indexes" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.default.exclusive_index_use" value="true" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.transaction.max_merge_docs" value="2" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.batch.max_merge_docs" value="2" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.merge_factor" value="2" />
<entry key="hibernate.search.default.indexwriter.ram_buffer_size" value="512" />
</util:map>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
<property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />

<bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" />
```

...

```
@Entity
@Table(name="job_search")
@Indexed
//NamedQueries...
public class JobSearch extends JobSearchBase implements Serializable {
..

/**
* @return the enabled
*/
@Column(name = "enabled", nullable = false)
@Field(name="enabled", store = Store.YES, index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, norms = Norms.YES)
public Boolean getEnabled() {
return enabled;
}
...
}
```

My Repository classes:

```
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public abstract class GenericJpaRepository<I extends Serializable, E extends Serializable> extends GenericBaseRepository<I, E> {

@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager entityManager;

//common crud operations
}

@Repository
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
public class JobSearchRepositoryImpl extends GenericJpaRepository<Long, JobSearch> implements JobSearchRepository, Serializable {
...

public void expireAndDisableJob(String jobReference) throws DataAccessException {

Query queryRecords = entityManager.createNamedQuery("JobSearch.findByJobReference");
queryRecords.setParameter("jobReference", jobReference);
List<JobSearch> searchList = queryRecords.getResultList();  
if (searchList.size() > 0) {
JobSearch jobSearch = searchList.get(0);
jobSearch.setEnabled(Boolean.FALSE);
}
}
}
```

My controller calls my service which calls the above repository class - all of which have:
@Transactional (propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
at the class level

when I run the code I get an exception (full stack trace below) when I try and update a Hibernate Search indexed field but it updates fine if I update an non-indexed field:

```
23:03:08,685 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-33) UT005023: Exception handling request to /advertiser/expire-and-disable/10121-1301-1439590822473: org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:982) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:168) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:205) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:120) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:96) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176) [spring-security-web-4.0.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform]; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:310) [spring-orm-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:221) [spring-orm-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:521) [spring-orm-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:761) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:730) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:485) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:291) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653) [spring-aop-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at uk.co.osmanincltd.fmdj.controller.AdvertiserLiveJobsController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2e968f27.expireAndDisableJob(<generated>) [spring-core-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601) [rt.jar:1.7.0_21]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:111) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:806) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:729) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
... 70 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.UnknownServiceException: Unknown service requested [org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.spi.JtaPlatform]
at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:201) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext.getService(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:139) [hibernate-search-orm-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext.isLocalTransaction(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:134) [hibernate-search-orm-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext.registerSynchronization(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:101) [hibernate-search-orm-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.TransactionalWorker.performWork(TransactionalWorker.java:90) [hibernate-search-engine-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener.processWork(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:243) [hibernate-search-orm-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.search.event.impl.FullTextIndexEventListener.onPostUpdate(FullTextIndexEventListener.java:218) [hibernate-search-orm-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.postUpdate(EntityUpdateAction.java:277) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:225) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:463) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:349) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:350) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:56) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1222) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:425) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:177) [hibernate-core-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:77) [hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.7.Final.jar:4.3.7.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:517) [spring-orm-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
... 91 more
```

This code works fine when it runs in an EJB3 SLSB with Hibernate and Hibernate Search but I can't understand why it fails when using Spring.

Searching over the Hibernate Search indexes works fine.

Thank you

Kind Regards
Kaz

Answer (score 0):

It is now working.

Just in case anyone else has this issue - I updated the hibernate and hibernate search versions in my maven pom (I also changed the scope for these to provided):

```
...
<hibernate-version>4.3.7.Final</hibernate-version>
<hibernate-search-version>4.5.1.Final</hibernate-search-version>
<hibernate-validator-version>5.1.3.Final</hibernate-validator-version>
...
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-search-engine</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-search-version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-search-orm</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-search-version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-infinispan</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
<artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
<version>${hibernate-validator-version}</version>
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
...
```